# Pesquisar uma String em um Input forms

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Estou tentando pesquisar uma string utilizando Javascript dentro do meu formulário, mas não consegui encontrar um método de fazê-lo. Por exemplo, tenho meu formulário com o campo "email" e gostaria de pesquisar o domínio digitado pelo usuário. Tentei já utilizar o `indexOf()` e o `includes()`, mas não obtive sucesso, alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como posso resolver esse problema utilizando JavaScript/jQuery?

Meu código HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="h1">Cadastro</div><br />
    <form id="formulario" method="get">
      <label for="nome"><b>Nome Completo</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Insira o nome" name="nome" id="nome" required>

      <label for="tel"><b>Telefone</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Insira o telefone" name="telefone" id="telefone">

      <label for="email"><b>E-mail</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="exemplo@exemplo.com.br" name="email" id="meu-email" required>

      <label for="data"><b>Data de nascimento</b></label>
      <input type="text" name="data" id="data">

      <input type="submit" name="event" value="Enviar" class="btncadastra" />
    </form><br />
  </div>

  <script src="cadastro.js"></script>
</body>
```

Meu código JavaScript:

```
var form = document.getElementById('formulario')
var campo = document.getElementById('meu-email')

form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
    if (campo.toString().includes("gmail.com")) {
        alert('é gmail!')
    } else {
        alert('não é!')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você utiliza métodos como `document.getElementById`, você receberá algum elemento do DOM. No caso de você selecionar um `<input />`, o elemento retornado implementará a interface [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Note que você está tentando acessar o **valor** do *input* (o que o usuário digitou) através do método `toString`. No entanto, veja o que este método realmente retorna:

```js
const field = document.getElementById('my-field');

console.log(field.toString()); // "[object HTMLInputElement]"
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my-field" value="Foo" />
```

Portanto, contatamos que o `toString` não irá retornar o valor digitado pelo usuário, mas sim a **representação textual** do objeto ao qual está anexado — no caso, `HTMLInputElement`.

Para acessar o valor do campo, utilize a propriedade `value`. Assim:

```js
const field = document.getElementById('my-field');

console.log(field.value); // "Foo"
```

```html
<input type="text" id="my-field" value="Foo" />
```

A partir disso, você pode utilizar métodos como o `String.prototype.includes` para verificar se o e-mail digitado é de um domínio específico. O problema mesmo só era o `toString`, que deveria ser `value`. Veja:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('formulario');
var campo = document.getElementById('meu-email');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    if (campo.value.includes("@gmail.com")) {
        alert('É Gmail!');
    } else {
        alert('Não é!');
    }
});
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
    <input type="email" id="meu-email" />
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

<sup>Note, como detalhe, que utilizei o método [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para prevenir a submissão padrão do formulário — já que estamos utilizando JavaScript para o manipular.</sup>

Comment: Ah entendi o que estava errado, muito obrigado pelo auxílio.. estava quebrando a cabeça para resolver este problema!

Comment: @CristianGuilhermePetry, se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema, não se esqueça de aceitá-la (clicando no ícone de check em seu canto superior esquerdo). Saiba mais no [tour].

Comment: Me surgiu uma questão agora, se eu fosse utilizar o SweetAlert2 para mostrar uma caixa de diálogo mais customizavel eu teria que codificar que o meu formulário fosse submetido depois que eu clicasse no botão OK na caixa de diálogo né? Porque senão a caixa de diálogo ficaria segundo e fecharia rapidamente já que o submit do forms atualiza a página logo quando envia.. seria nessa linha?